# ASP.NET Core non existent static file request resolves to fallback

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, single-page-application, static-files

Using the boilerplate dotnet react app (created via `dotnet new react`) - a request to a non existent static file (for example https://localhost:5001/static/js/idonotexist.js ) will return an unmatched react route as a 200.

The Startup.cs in this boilerplate solution does already include

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
```

My question is - how do I make the above request return a 404, instead of resolving to the default/fallback SPA route ?

Thanks

Comment: According to the [`UseSpa()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaapplicationbuilderextensions.usespa?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_SpaApplicationBuilderExtensions_UseSpa_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_SpaServices_ISpaBuilder__) documents:

> Handles all requests from this point in the middleware chain by returning the default page for the Single Page Application (SPA).

your expected behavior is not supported by default.